# How can I use the ets() or holt() functions in R to duplicate the results from Excel 2016 forecast.ets?

Tags: r, excel

I have tried a lot of combinations of both `holt()` and `ets()` in the R forecast package but cannot duplicate the results from `=forecast.ets` in Excel 2016 and later. I work for a regulated gas utility and relying on black-box Excel results that cannot be verified/duplicated is not an option. I would like to be able to duplicate the Excel results in R.

The "problem" is that with my data `=forecast.ets` in Excel results in more accurate forecasts than `holt()` in R.

I am using the `holt()` function from the forecast package as my data is not seasonal. I have tried various combinations of providing my own optimum alpha and beta values as well as allowing `holt()` to set them. I have used the alpha and beta parameters that Excel creates but am unable to reconcile the results.

```
#Normally the data comes via ODBC, but this is the same thing
upc <- data_frame(Result=c(296,292,284,286,286,
273,282,276,273,294,284,290,293,293,288))

#Turn the table into a time series from 2003 to 2017
upc.ts <- ts(upc$Result, start=2003, end=2017, frequency=1)

#Use 2003 to 2015 to develop the model
train <- window(upc.ts, start=2003, end=2015)

#Use holt to get the forecast value for 2016 and 2017
holt.upc <- holt(train, h = 2)

#The result:
#Point Forecast      Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
#2016       298.1118 286.5946 309.6290 280.4977 315.7259
#2017       303.4814 290.4835 316.4792 283.6029 323.3599
```

For the 2016 value the formula 
    `=FORECAST.ETS(2016,B2:B14,A2:A14,0,0)` 
in Excel = 286.45 (nowhere close to the 298.11 from `holt()`).
The actual 2016 value was 293.2.

For the 2017 value the formula 
    `=FORECAST.ETS(2017,B2:B14,A2:A14,0,0)` 
in Excel = 286.27 (nowhere close to the 303.48 from `holt()`).
The actual 2016 value was 288.4.

I have 20 similar forecasts to complete and results in the others are similar.

I am trying to duplicate the Excel results using R.

Comment: I havent got a full answer as I dont have Excel, but instead of using the `holt()` function, you may want to look at `forecast::ets()` which might give you more control over the type of ETS model used. I also see you have set seasonality = 0 in Excel. This may just fit some sort of linear fit?

Comment: I understand `holt()` is a wrapper for `ets()`. I worked with `ets()` extensively and tried all the different combinations that made sense. My data is annual natural gas consumption. It has a strong downward trend (customers use less every year) so there is no seasonality. Excel does not show the "fit" like `ets()` and `holt()` but based on the alpha and beta output from Excel some models are linear. I should add that the most confounding thing is that Excel always outperforms `ets()` with my data in terms of h=2 forecast accuracy, which the regulator is most interested in.